# ORA-00928 missing SELECT keyword in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using the following code to insert data. But I'm receiving an error as `"ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword"`

```
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx:xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
String query="insert into offer1('RCODE','OFFERNO','DAT') values(?,?,?)"; 
    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1,r_code);
    ps.setString(2,offerno);
    ps.setDate(3,sqlDate);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    out.println("data inserted");
}catch(Exception e)
 {
     out.println(e);
 }
```

I can't see any errors in this code. If someone finds, please tell me what is the mistake and how to solve it?

Comment: There are totally 2 problems one is remove the sigle quotes for the column names and instead of using `executeQuery()` use `executeUpdate()`  and more over for insert statement what resultset are you expecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the single quotes, try

```
String query="insert into offer1(RCODE,OFFERNO,DAT) values(?,?,?)";
```

Comment: The real solution would of course be for the database to give a correct error message, this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 9):

single quotes are for string literals not for *identifiers* only so you should remove it around the columnNames.

```
INSERT INTO offer1 (RCODE,OFFERNO,DAT) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

and use `executeUpdate` since you are not retrieving records which results a *resultset*.

from *DOCS*

boolean **execute**()

- Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.

ResultSet **executeQuery**()

- Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

int **executeUpdate**()

- Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
String query="insert into offer1(RCODE,OFFERNO,DAT) values(?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Please explain it in detail!

Answer (score 2):

I was running the same issue, and in my case the query was like this:

```
insert into Address (number, street, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

The problem was caused by the `number` column name since `number` is a reserved keyword in Oracle, and the exception was "ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword".

So, the `number` column name must be escaped, like this:

```
insert into Address ("number", street, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Statement.executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet executeQuery()
```

Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

```
int executeUpdate()
```

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

So instead of using `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();` use int result = ps.executeUpdate();

it returns either the row count for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements, or 0 for SQL statements that return nothing