# Remove row if values in one column if found in another in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table below where I have two columns per client.  I want to delete rows in Column B if it is in Column A per Client.  In this example we would remove rows with "123" in Column B for Tom since it is in Column A.
Sorry for the confusion.

| Client | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 123 | 560 |
| Tom | 544 | 123 |
| Bob | 658 | 85 |
| Tom | 32 | 123 |
| Sean | 45 | 105 |

Output

| Client | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 123 | 560 |
| Bob | 658 | 85 |
| Sean | 45 | 105 |

Comment: You remove rows with `DELETE`. You find out if a row exists with `EXISTS`. (You can also use `IN` for this.) What exactly are you having problems with? Do my hints already help you solve this?

Comment: wouldn't this leave you with no records at all with the same values? Is that exactly what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: @groovy_guy, apologies my initial post wasn't clear.   I've edited the question/example.  Basically I'm looking to remove a row if a value in Column B is found in Column A per client.

Comment: Okay, you want to remove duplicate cients, so as to stay with one row per client. (Once you have done so, you should probably implement a unique constraint on that column in order not to get duplicates in the future.) How do you decide for a row to keep? Why is it Tom|123|560 you are keeping and not one of the other Tom entries?

Comment: And again: What exactly is it you are having troubles with? What keeps you from writing a `DELETE` statement with `EXISTS`?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Your SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: You have changed your title to Oracle, so I added the Oracle tag for you. But why don't you answer the question? What makes you pick Tom|123|560 for Tom? What rule applies here? Or doesn't it matter which row to keep per name?

Comment: Thank you.  You can think of it this another way, Column A is like the product Tom has now, Column B is the product we can offer.  We wouldn't want to offer Tom a product he already has (in Column A).

Comment: Okay. And you want to remove rows, i.e. delete them from the table? Or do you just want to select the clients with their current products and leave the original table unchanged?

Comment: yes the rows can be removed

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE tableclients FROM tableclients
WHERE columnB IN (SELECT columnA from tableclients)
```

This should work out,
It's a simple and effective query hope you'll get your required results from it

Comment: oh I actually wrote that query elsewhere and posted the same It'll also work without `back quotes \` `

Comment: . . This code still won't work in Oracle.  It is the right idea, but you should use DB Fiddle or a similar tool to get working code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've come across some of your answers before I'm pretty sure you might be having answers for this too. and I'm confused with this one. It'd be really helpful If you can guide how this could be solved :)

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle.  You can test Oracle queries at https://dbfiddle.uk/, for instance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your help. I checked on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and the updated query seems to be working in there here's the markdown https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61de1fa1feaa73efb73e1cf9ce5ca639

Comment: Thanks, I'm adding as subquery and getting the error ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword, thoughts?

Comment: @indyanahh for ORA-00928 [check if this post helps you out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14722483/15405352)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either not exists clause or not in clause to do that.

```sql
select t1.*
from Your_Table t1
where not exists (
  select null 
  from Your_Table t2 
  where t2.Client = t1.Client and t2.Column_A = t1.Column_B
  )
;
```

or

```sql
select t1.*
from Your_Table t1
where (t1.Client, t1.Column_B) not in (
  select t2.Client, t2.Column_A 
  from Your_Table t2
)
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b52b6d9b9f6a67c5ea17cba04a75dfc2)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.
this is the **MySql** procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBname.deleteRecord()
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp`;
create table temp select    b.Column2  as Column2  from  
clienttable  a  inner join 
clienttable  b where  a.Column1  = b.Column2 AND a.client  =   b.client ; 

delete   FROM  clienttable  WHERE  Column2 in (select  b.Column2    
from  temp b );

SELECT * from  clienttable ;


END
```

Call

call DBname.deleteRecord()

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
declare @TableIntersect table(Name nvarchar(max))

insert into @TableIntersect(Name) SELECT Name  
    FROM ColumnA  
    INTERSECT  
    SELECT Name
    FROM ColumnB

delete from YourTable where ColumnA in (select Name from @TableIntersect)
delete from YourTable where ColumnB in (select Name from @TableIntersect)
```

Comment: This answer is DBMS specific. SQL Server maybe? It is unecessarily extensive (and a bit flawed), too. The original request "where b exists in a" could be solved with a mere `delete from t where b in (select a from t)`.